# AndroidStudio emulator cannot take photo: The camera device has encountered a serious error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, android-emulator

I'm working with an Android emulator (api 29) and when I try to capture a photo like this:

```
imageCapture?.takePicture(cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
...
  override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
   ....
   // should show a preview before sending the picture to the web service
  }

}
```

it freezes. This only happens with an emulator!

I have the following error:

```
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@683e74c[id=0]} Resetting Capture Session
E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2521)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1128)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:526)
```

Comment: Me too. Only on Android 12 emulator. What is your cameraX version?

Comment: Hi! the version is 1.0.2 and yours?

Comment: If you have the same question, can you give un up to the post? so more people can see it, and maybe answer it? @Krahmal

Comment: I voted. Mine is 1.1.0-alpha04. I think this may caused by emulator bug...

Comment: Device Manager>Edit>Show Advanced Settings>Camera>Back, change it from virtual scene to emulated, and the emulator can take picture now for me.

Comment: yes but I need to take a real picture :/

Comment: I have Samsung A32 phone with android 12 , my code working on it and when i am using pixel 2 xl with api level 33 emulator it gives this error

Comment: @ladytoky0 did u find any solution. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @SVG I did not find any solution, only that apparently it's impossible lol

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced this same problem in pixel 3 (sdk 31). This was indeed the problem with the emulator.

Thanks to #Krahmal (Topic's main comment section) helped to fixed a part of the  problem but not 100%

For my case pixel 4 with android 10 (sdk 29) working fine(which may not in your case).
Although it works with physical device.

Thanks